# How can I use vertex colors as an input in my material?

Tags: materials, vertex-colors

I want to use vertex colors as a mix factor in my material. However when I chose Add->Input the option Vertex Colors doesn't show up. Why can I not access the vertex colors data? I want to avoid using any python scripts or any workarounds with the Attribute node if possible.
Using Blender 2.8.

[image]

Comment: @Robert Gützkow I actually read that thread beforehand, but I feel like there should be a more intuitive way.

Comment: @Frederik Steinmetz thanks for the suggestion, I will probably use the addon. Sometimes I'm getting very sick of blender. I'm kind of a minimalistic person wanting to do minimalistic things and I can't wrap my head around why this seems to be a problem and needs some (third party?) addon.

Comment: 2.81 has that node finally

Comment: @HenrikD oh really? perfect, downloading it right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Blender version 2.81 has this exact same feature natively built in. For older versions, you can enable the Node Wrangler addon for a similar feature, or you have to use the Attribute node (which for me is not the most elegant solution but works just fine). Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Even easier than the suggestiong of @Robert Gützkopf: Enable the Node Wrangler Addon. It will put that option exactly where you pointed out it's missing.